# store into variable a sudo result

Tags: linux, unix, shell, centos

I have this simple script

```
#!/bin/sh
ISUP=`sudo /etc/init.d/jboss7 status | grep running`
echo "ISUP: " $ISUP
```

if I run it manually it works fine

```
[jboss@suc072-ipos ~]$ sh a.sh
ISUP:  JBoss AS 7.1.1 is running (pid 29125)
```

but if I run it with crontab the variable is empty :O :(

```
* * * * * /home/jboss/a.sh > /home/jboss/a.log
[jboss@suc072-ipos ~]$ cat a.log
ISUP:
```

any idea how to fix this?

linux centos

```
[jboss@suc072-ipos ~]$ cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 6.7 (Final)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have configured sudo for the account this cron job is running under to not require a password and you have also modified `/etc/sudoers` to comment out the line `Defaults    requiretty` and (possibly) added /`etc/init.d/` to the secure path this [will always fail](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49077/why-does-cron-silently-fail-to-run-sudo-stuff-in-my-script) when run noninteractively like it does in a cronjob.

Instead, the vastly preferred method is to set up the cron job to run as root and remove sudo from the script. To add a cronjob that will run as root use the command:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Add the cronjob in the same way you did previously.

Then remove the sudo from the script, here with some other minor cleanup/suggested changes:

```
#!/bin/bash
ISUP="$(/etc/init.d/jboss7 status | grep running)"
echo "ISUP:  $ISUP"
```

Comment: thanks for the info, I guess that is why also is failing with this error
sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo